# PySpark: Pivot only one row to column

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe like so:
`df = sc.parallelize([("num1", "1"), ("num2", "5"), ("total", "10")]).toDF(("key", "val"))`

```
key     val
num1    1
num2    5
total   10
```

I want to pivot only the `total` row to a new column and keep its value for each row:

```
key     val   total
num1    1     10
num2    5     10
```

I've tried pivoting and aggregating but cannot get the one column with the same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could join a dataframe with only the total to a dataframe without the total.

Another option would be to collect the total and add it as a literal.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

# option 1    
df1 = df.filter("key <> 'total'")
df2 = df.filter("key = 'total'").select(f.col('val').alias('total'))

df1.join(df2).show()

+----+---+-----+                                                                
| key|val|total|
+----+---+-----+
|num1|  1|   10|
|num2|  5|   10|
+----+---+-----+

# option 2
total = df.filter("key = 'total'").select('val').collect()[0][0]
df.filter("key <> 'total'").withColumn('total', f.lit(total)).show()

+----+---+-----+                                                                
| key|val|total|
+----+---+-----+
|num1|  1|   10|
|num2|  5|   10|
+----+---+-----+
```